# gnuplot: how to plot color squares for each month's temperature?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the following figure (from [Fundamentals of Data Visualization](https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/aesthetic-mapping.html#scales-map-data-values-onto-aesthetics)) using gnuplot:

[image: color]

I expect the data for each location is something like:

```
# month temperature
01 60.0
02 78.0
03 90.0
...
12 78.0
```

---

Here is what I tried. For simplicity, I have transposed the data into a matrix.

```
$data << EOD
1.50 1.57 1.85 2.15 1.87 1.05 1.70 1.65 1.97 1.71 1.53 1.15
4.44 4.71 4.74 3.50 3.43 4.98 4.29 4.55 3.93 3.34 3.74 4.88
8.55 9.59 5.65 0.13 9.33 4.70 8.94 7.74 4.49 6.26 0.96 1.20
EOD

unset border
unset ytics
set xlabel 'month'

set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
set cbrange [0:10]
set cblabel "precipitation"
set xrange [-0.5:11.5]
set yrange [-0.5:2.5]
set xtics ("Jan" 0, "Feb" 1, "Mar" 2, "Apr" 3, "May" 4, \
"Jun" 5, "Jul" 6, "Aug" 7, "Sep" 8, "Oct" 9, "Nov" 10, "Dec" 11)
plot $data matrix with image
```

But the effect is far from satisfactory. For example, How to generate clear borders between squares?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plotting style `with image` probably cannot have borders. So, I would use the versatile style `with boxxyerror`.
Furthermore, instead of matrix format I would add a line header and loop through the columns (since there will be always 12 months)
Check the following example as well as `help boxxyerror`, `help size`, `help xticlabels` and `help strftime` for further reading.

If you have your data in separate files you would have to modify the script accordingly.

**Script:**

```
### plotting style boxxyerror as replacement for "with image"
reset session

$Data << EOD
# location  Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
Atlantis    1.50  1.57  1.85  2.15  1.87  1.05  1.70  1.65  1.97  1.71  1.53  1.15
Mordor      4.44  4.71  4.74  3.50  3.43  4.98  4.29  4.55  3.93  3.34  3.74  4.88
Wonderland  8.55  9.59  5.65  0.13  9.33  4.70  8.94  7.74  4.49  6.26  0.96  1.20
EOD

unset border
set xlabel 'month'
set xrange [0.5:12.5]

set yrange [:] reverse
set ytics

set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
set cbrange [0:10]
set cblabel "precipitation"

MonthName(n) = strftime("%b",24*3600*28*n)      # get the month name from 1..12
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 1.0 border rgb "white"
set size ratio -1       # make the boxes squares

plot for [i=1:12] $Data u (i):0:(0.5):(0.5):i+1:  \
        xtic(MonthName(i)):ytic(1) w boxxy fc palette lw 2
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You are a grand master of gnuplot!